# How can I compare two class with void* in cpp

Tags: c++, class, compare

How can I compare two class with void* in cpp.
I compare day and month.
What can I do in compare_dayOfYear function?

This is my class:

```
class DayOfYear
{

public:
    DayOfYear(int newMonth,int newDay);
    //Initializes the month and day to arguments.

    DayOfYear(int newMonth);
    //Initializes the date to the first of the given month.

    DayOfYear();
    //Initializes the date to January 1.

    // Accessors
    int getMonthNumber( );
    //Returns 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.
    int getDay( );

    // Mutators
    int setMonthNumber(int newMonth);
    //Set 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.
    int setDay(int newDay);

private:
    int month;
    int day;
};


bool compare_dayOfYear(const void * firstValue, const void * secondValue)
{
    //I compare day and month
    //What can I do here
}
```

How can I compare two class with void* in cpp.
I compare day and month.
What can I do in compare_dayOfYear function?

Comment: No you can't without casting. Why do you need to use `void*` at all?

Comment: Don't use `void*`, just use `DayOfYear`

Comment: int return_mode (const void * base, size_t num, size_t size,
                bool (* equals) (const void *, const void *)); I  have this function. ı send the compare_dayOfYear this function.

Comment: You need to read about *casting*.

Comment: Why do you want to pass `void*`? That's all kinds of a bad idea, where you'd better know what exactly you are doing and why.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) and at [related video from CppCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you've passed `DayOfYear` objects then you can just cast the `void` pointers.

```
bool compare_dayOfYear(const void * firstValue, const void * secondValue)
{
  DayOfYear* firstDayOfYear = static_cast<DayOfYear*>(firstValue);
  DayOfYear* secondDayOfYear = static_cast<DayOfYear*>(secondValue);
  //compare..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `compare_dayOfYear` function, you should use the following operator overloads...

```
bool operator==(DayOfYear const &lhs, DayOfYear const &rhs)
{
  return const_cast<DayOfYear &>(lhs).getMonthNumber() == 
    const_cast<DayOfYear &>(rhs).getMonthNumber() &&
      const_cast<DayOfYear &>(lhs).getDay() == const_cast<DayOfYear &>(rhs).getDay();
}

bool operator!=(DayOfYear const &lhs, DayOfYear const &rhs)
{
  return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

(the `const_cast`s are necessary because your `getMonthNumber` and `getDay` accessors are not declared `const` - they probably should be if they don't modify `month` and `day`)

Now you can compare two `DayOfYear` instances using built-in operators `==` and `!=`...

```
DayOfYear a(2, 1), b(2, 1), c(3, 1);
assert(a == b);
assert(a != c);
```

If you really must use your `compare_dayOfYear` function as-is then it should be implemented on top of the operator overloads like so...

```
bool compare_dayOfYear(const void * firstValue, const void * secondValue)
{
  return *static_cast<DayOfYear const*>(firstValue) ==
    *static_cast<DayOfYear const*>(secondValue);
}
```